# Can you insert a column into a row like you can a row into a column in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```dart
Row (
   children: [
      Column (
         children: [
            //children
         ]
      ),
      Column (
         children: [
            //children
         ]
      )
   ]
),
```

I want to create one column that contains buttons and a textfield to take input from the user and another column that allows that data to be outputted. But when I try to nest a column as one of the children of a row, I keep getting a null error.

Comment: can you show the entire codebase 'cause your code runs fine on dartpad 
https://dartpad.dev/1a28bdd9203250d3226cc25d512579ec?null_safety=true

Answer (score 0):

Elaborate your question and share the code snippet to get accurate answers. Try to add the "error message".